# Max area of an island of 1's in a 2D array

Tags: python

The [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-area-of-island/) reads the following:

> Given a non-empty 2D array grid of 0's and 1's, an island is a group
> of 1's (representing land) connected 4-directionally (horizontal or
> vertical.) You may assume all four edges of the grid are surrounded by
> water.
>
> Find the maximum area of an island in the given 2D array. (If there is
> no island, the maximum area is 0.)

```
class Solution:

    def maxAreaOfIsland( self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        a = len(grid)
    
        
        for x in range(0, a):
            b = len(grid[x])
            for y in range(0 , b):
                if grid[x][y] == "1":
                    self.dfs(grid , x , y)
        
        return count
                    
    def dfs(self,grid, i, j):
        count = 0
        
        if i < 0 or i >= len(grid) or j < 0 or j >= len(grid[0]) or grid[i][j] == "0" or grid[i][j] == "2":
            return 
        
        grid[i][j] = "2"
        count += 1
    
        self.dfs(grid , i-1 , j)
        self.dfs(grid , i+1, j)
        self.dfs(grid, i , j-1)
        self.dfs(grid , i , j+1)
```

I am trying to use depth-first search method to find neighbors. However, I have no idea how to increment count correctly when finding "1" as well as outputing the total count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to increase the count in a recursive function it should be a class variable or a global variable. You also try to reset it to 0 each time you get into the dfs, which is not fine, because your dfs function will call itself and reset that count to 0. Your basic idea is fine, you tag your already visited parts as being a "2". The only thing that could also be changed is the checking you do on the edges. The problem states that you can assume the edges are all 0's, so you can just begin iterating from position 1,1 instead of 0,0, because you will never get outside of the map by doing a dfs.

The place where you should reset the count is in the maxAreaOfIsland function, whenever you find a '1' tile. Also you can check after the dfs if it's greater then the maximum you found.

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0   # You need the count to be visible for both functions, so you can declare it here
        self._maxCount = 0 # Max count doesn't have to be declared here, you can also declare it inside maxAreaOfIsland   

    def maxAreaOfIsland(self, grid):
        a = len(grid)


        for x in range(0, a):
            b = len(grid[x])
            for y in range(0 , b):
                if grid[x][y] == "1":
                    self._count = 0   # Here you reset the count
                    self.dfs(grid , x , y)
                    if self._count > self._maxCount:  # Here you check if it's greater than the max
                        self._maxCount = self._count

        return self._maxCount

    def dfs(self,grid, i, j):

        if i < 0 or i >= len(grid) or j < 0 or j >= len(grid[0]) or grid[i][j] == "0" or grid[i][j] == "2":
            return 

        grid[i][j] = "2"
        self._count += 1 # Here you increment the count

        self.dfs(grid , i-1 , j)
        self.dfs(grid , i+1, j)
        self.dfs(grid, i , j-1)
        self.dfs(grid , i , j+1)
```

Comment: I tried running this program. But the output is wrong.

Comment: Well, are you sure you have strings in your list and not ints? If yes, do you get an error or do you constantly get 0 as a result? I just ran it into an online interpreter but it seems to give fine results, except the errors from the bad indentation and the errors that you had because you forgot to change in dfs your indexes. You were using i and j in dfs not x and y. @user12852585

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without recursivity by building a dictionary of coordinates (sets) for the positions that are on land.  Then merge these sets for each land position that connects to the right or below other land positions.  The result will be a common set of positions at all positions that are connected.  The length of the largest of these sets will be the area of the largest island:

```
def maxIsland(grid):
    rows,cols = len(grid),len(grid[0])
    land      = { (r,c):{(r,c)} for r in range(rows) for c in range(cols) if grid[r][c] }
    for (r,c) in list(land):
        for nr,nc in [(r+1,c),(r,c+1)]:            # Positions below/right 
            if (nr,nc) not in land:  continue      # connecting land 
            if land[r,c] is land[nr,nc]: continue  # skip already merged
            land[r,c].update(land[nr,nc])          # Merge set of positions 
            for (lr,lc) in land[nr,nc]: 
                land[lr,lc] = land[r,c]            # Propagate merged set to all
    return max(map(len,land.values()))             # return size of largest set
```

output:

```
world = [ "0000000000000",
          "0111000000111",
          "0101110000111",
          "0100111100111",
          "0100000100000",
          "0101001110000",
          "0111001110000" ]
world = [ list(map(int,row)) for row in world ]

print( maxIsland(world) ) # 25
```

For an even more basic approach, you could work from a set of land coordinates and progressively take out the coordinates that are connected into islands while measuring the island sizes.   Islands can be formed by expanding one land coordinate, adding uncharted neighbours and expanding the newly added positions of the island:

```
def maxIsland(grid):
    rows,cols = len(grid),len(grid[0])
    land      = { (r,c) for r in range(rows) for c in range(cols) if grid[r][c] }
    result    = 0
    while land:                    # find new islands in uncharted land
        island    = [land.pop()]           # pick a coordinate to expand into an island
        expanding = 0                      # will expand coordinates added by expansion
        while expanding<len(island):
            r,c = island[expanding]                         # expand added coordinate 
            neighbours = {(r+1,c),(r-1,c),(r,c+1),(r,c-1)}  # candidate coordinates
            island    += list(land & neighbours)            # add uncharted land to island
            land      -= neighbours                         # remove from uncharted land
            expanding += 1                                  
        result = max(result,len(island))   # track largest island
    return result
```

*Note: this will run much faster than the first one on large grids*

Answer (score 0):

In the last approach which uses the  dictionary of coordinates (sets) for the positions that are on land, if i find that the size of largest set is composed of 8 connected coordinates pairs;
how do i only obtain the first five connected coordinates and its corresponding values
in the matrix?
To obtain the values ​​of the matrix associated with the connected coordinates of the maximum island, I tried
the following method

```
        data = list(land.items())
        data_1= sorted(data) # sort the list of coordinate pairs for length
        an_array = np.array(data_1)
        islands= max(map(len,land.values()))
        if islands >1:
            arr = an_array[islands-1][1]
            for i in arr:
                listx.append(i[0])
                listy.append(i[1])
            
            for ix,iy,zip(range(len(listx)),range(len(listx)),listx,listy):
                    matrix=grid[list1[i]][list2[i]]
                    print "Coordinate X",listx[ix],"Coordinate Y ",listy[iy],"Values in the matrix" ,matrix
```

but i am not able  to get the first five connected coordinates and its values
corresponding in the matrix.

PLEASE NOTE:  i work with matrix of different numerical values