# List index error for finding largest cluster in 2-D array

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, gaps-and-islands

I have been trying to work with this code a friend sent to me, to help find the largest connected series of 1s in a given array.

First I am hard coding in the data for the grid, rows and columns as you can see in the code provided. The grid will always have 3 columns but the rows will vary in length, and with this, I am having the repeated problem of my list having an "index out of range" error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this, as I ju8st can't think of the answer myself.

```
# Python3 program
row = 6
col = 3

vis = [[0 for i in range(col + 1)] for j in range(row + 1)] 
id = 0
diameter = 0
length = 0

# Keeps a track of directions
# that is up, down, left, right
dx = [ -1, 1, 0, 0 ]
dy = [ 0, 0, -1, 1 ]

# Function to perform the dfs traversal
def dfs(a, b, lis, x, y):
    
    global id, length, diameter
    
    # Mark the current node as visited
    vis[a][b] = id

    # Increment length from this node
    length += 1

    # Update the diameter length
    if (length > diameter):
        x = a
        y = b
        diameter = length
    
    for j in range(4):

        # Move to next cell in x-direction
        cx = a + dx[j]

        # Move to next cell in y-direction
        cy = b + dy[j]

        # Check if cell is invalid
        # then continue
        if (cx < 0 or cy < 0 or
            cx >= row or cy >= col or
            lis[cx][cy] == 0 or vis[cx][cy]):
            continue
    
        # Perform DFS on new cell
        dfs(cx, cy, lis, x, y)
    
    vis[a][b] = 0

    # Decrement the length
    length -= 1
    
    return x, y

# Function to find the maximum length of
# connected 1s in the given grid
def findMaximumLength(lis):
    
    global id, length, diameter
    
    x = 0
    y = 0

    # Increment the id
    id += 1
    
    length = 0
    diameter = 0

    # Traverse the grid[]
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            if (lis[i][j] != 0):

                # Find start point of
                # start dfs call
                x, y = dfs(i, j, lis, x, y)
                i = row
                break

    id += 1
    length = 0
    diameter = 0

    # DFS Traversal from cell (x, y)
    x, y = dfs(x, y, lis, x, y)

    # Print the maximum length
    print(diameter)

# Driver Code
if __name__=="__main__":
    
    # Given grid[][]
    grid = [ [ 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ],
            [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ]

    # Function Call
    findMaximumLength(grid)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using global variables in a recursive function is usually wrong. I suggest you check whether these variables have the desired value when you're using them.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend hardcoded `row` and `col` variables. `row` and `col` variables should match your grid shape. You have 3x6 and the parameters are 6x3.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit more searching I have found a piece of code that gets the results I want with also minimal coding:

[Max area of an island of 1's in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61319843/max-area-of-an-island-of-1s-in-a-2d-array)